# Widget creation: Access-Control-Allow-Origin, and session issues, how can I solve it?

Tags: php, session, widget

I'm creating a widget (with PHP and jQuery) to be included in a hosting webpage, 
and actually I'm kind of stuck because of these two isseus i'm describing below:

1. In my widget there are commands that are supposed to perform AJAX calls to php script to 
   retrieve data, but I always got access-Control-Allow-Origin errors,  initially I thought I solved this issue placing this line in php:
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
   But it is working until now only on firefox, Chrome still refuse to give me the php output
2. Always talking about the AJAX calls : the user performs choices lauching these calls, I'd like to track user choices. I thought to use sessions with PHP. The problem here is that any call seems to have a different session_id... any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Take a look at [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)
2. You can generate (probably get?) a user ID from javascript and then send it along with request.

Explanations for your issue #2: PHP sessions work with cookies and GET parameters. PHP generates sessions ID and puts it to either cookie or GET string. Then, when request comes back, it reads the cookie (GET param) and knows which sessions to pick up. In your case you get cookies from the original page (not your domain) and thus no session id (that belongs to your server) is in and your server has nothing to do except generate the new one.

As an option you may consider embedding your widget with `iframe` and it will solve all your issues including same origin and session handling.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I took a look at JSONP before posting my question. But actually I didnt find a solution. The part where they talk about "Padding" and how to put thigs together to make them work isn't very clear. ANd there's also another issue, because they solve the problem embedding a <script> tag inside the page. But they do not talk about user interactions e.g. a user who click a button inside the widget that is supposed to perform a AJAX request on another domain to a serverside script to get more dynamic contents...Maybe I've missed some piece?

Comment: Essentially, instead of performing AJAX request you append `script` tag to the page which has URL like `http://server/path?f=doSmth`. `doSmth` is the function on client page which should take data. On your server you just add it to the JSON response like `doSmth({name:val, name2:val2});` When this script loads, it simply calls your `doSmth` function giving it server response. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use pure AJAX with jQuery/JavaScript you may want to consider looking at how to generate a cookie along with the request.  The cookie is merely added as part of the headers being sent along with your request being made, and all you need to do is inject the current user's session cookie back into any AJAX requests being made to ensure that the user is still being considered the same user for each request your widget would be making to other scripts in the background.  It's been a while since I've used jQuery/JavaScript for these types of requests, but I believe there is a way to add headers to the request before sending it.  You may need to make raw cookies for the header, but a simple Google search should reveal the format you need.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to give an answer to my question just to help someone who's in my same trouble.

If using Javascript/Jquery is not a must to realize your widget, I've found that 
realizing your widget as a Adobe Flash swf application will solve all issues above.

With AS3 you can perform remote Http requests to php files. And all request will be tracked as single session. And there's no issues with Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

domainhost.com can load the into tag  domain1.com/widgetflash.php
and then the loaded widget.swf inside the page can perform remote request like this:

```
urlRequest= new URLRequest("http://www.example.com/source/setChoice.php");
_urlLoader = new URLLoader(); 
_urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onXMLDataLoaded, false, 0, true);
_urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
```

Comment: You will face ad blockers problem and experience issues with mobile browsers. For example, iPad is a good device to visit your site, but it has no Flash Player in it. So your widget won't work at all. Why not embed your widget as iframe? You will not need to do any extra work. Even if you want to give users a "script" way of adding your widget, your script can embed iframe automatically. It will solve all your problems!

Comment: All true but Mobile world isn't an issue for me at the moment. Since my layout isn't optimized for small screens. And I still believe that at this time any webapp should have two different version, mobile and largescreen. I'ts a matter of layout and usability. The IFRAME way is acutally the last chance, less elegant but still a good and easier chance. On the other hand I can tell that Flash even if not widely compatible with all devices could still help for UserExperience. Anyway I still like to make it work like a Jquery widget, I believe there should be a way.